# Is consistently answering another user's questions considered vote fraud?

Tags: discussion, voting-fraud, sock-puppets

Recently I made a friend on Stack Overflow. I answered one of his questions pretty well, and the answer must have helped him out substantially. He had some more questions so I spent some time talking to him about the subject he was asking about.

Since I answered the first question pretty well, he will message me when he asks another question on Stack Overflow. Most of the time when I am in this situation, I am able to provide a good answer, which warrants upvotes/accepting the answer.

**Would consistently answering these questions be considered vote fraud or sock-puppetry?**

**Should I answer these questions or should I ignore them?**

Comment: If you answers his questions, fine. If you answers ONLY his questions, that will probably raise a red flag to moderators.

Comment: Considering the fact that after asking a question and when a question has no answers, you are asked "know someone who can answer? Share [...] via e-mail [...] or Facebook" I assume it's perfectly allowed to encourage your friends to come answer. If you are otherwise not the kind of person to browse SO, and only come here when someone shares a link to you, which seems encouraged, I don't think there should be penalty for doing so. Of course, while you're here feel free to vote and answer other questions!

Comment: If the goal of Stack Overflow is to help each other with programming issues, choosing to ignore his question which you have knowledge to help with would seem to be counter productive.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As stated, there's nothing inherently wrong with answering more of a specific user's questions if you find each other's posts interesting enough to spend time on. You just need to be careful that you don't end up

- voting on only or mostly their questions and not others
- aggressively competing with other users who may come across and answer their questions alongside you, or otherwise taking it personally (which I've been through myself on a few occasions, so I understand how it feels)

Some tips to alleviate these concerns:

- Avoid making explicit arrangements to ask and answer each other too often (I wouldn't bat an eye if you did this once in a while when you're both free at the time). Have your friend continue posting their questions as normal and evaluate any answers that turn up. You don't want your friend to start depending on you for answers. If your friend still doesn't receive a satisfactory answer, or you don't find any of the existing answers satisfactory, feel free to add your own. What's important is that their questions get answers that are useful to the community, regardless of who provides these answers.
- Don't stop answering other questions you may find interesting and useful to answer. There are lots of bad questions to sift through, but by no means a drought of good/interesting questions. Having said that, don't feel like you have to meet some sort of quota — moderators are pretty good at telling whether or not a user that's answering only specific users is doing so in good or bad faith and/or gaming the system in doing so.
- Remember to vote on other questions you spend time on, and not just your friend's questions, and remind your friend to consider and vote on other people's answers as well. On the flip side, abstaining from voting on each other's posts is safest if you feel that your personal biases may sway you into upvoting anything written by each other.
- "Asking good questions is hard" is something you'll hear a lot on meta, and with good reason. If they ask a question that you know does not meet quality standards, help them out with an edit or a comment; use it as a teaching moment so they can ask better questions in the future.
- Remember that you're not the only one who can answer your friend's questions, and you're not the only ones who can vote on each other's posts. Votes from other readers will decide if your questions and answers are useful and which of the answers to these questions are more useful than the others, and I'm sure your good answers to your friend's questions will attract more than just your friend's upvote.

Comment: Really? Isn't this guilty until proven innocent? What if a user only visits rarely, like when he gets mentioned by his friend to answer a question, then does so, and doesn't come back until the next mention...That is surely not wrong? Better than ignoring the mention just to avoid the wrath of an AI which is watching. You can't penalize someone for only answering certain questions, surely...I do think  though, this is tough to Police but innocence rules.

Comment: @Darren Sweeney: I'm afraid so. Most people who start out doing this wind up in the trap of biasing their votes to low quality content you would never upvote in good conscience just because it was written by their friends. But you're right: I shouldn't have to feel obligated to answer other people's questions organically just so I can continue answering my friend's, and I shouldn't have to worry that the moderators will come after me just because I have no interest in answering questions unless I'm summoned.

Comment: @Darren Sweeney: I think a lot of these expectations are built around the fact that most people do come to the site to participate organically, and those who only show up when summoned by specific users very rarely do so with the purest of motives. But we do examine a user's contributions and voting history closely when their profile comes up in our tools for suspicious voting and you have my word that we'll at the very least switch to innocent until proven guilty at that stage. We don't question someone in a mod message unless they're found guilty or seem at risk of falling into that trap.

Comment: @pnuts: I think that's different. The AI only ever acts on bursts of votes cast on another user's posts. If you diligently vote on another user's posts as they post rather than waiting for an opportunity to vote on a series of posts at one go (hence the term *serial* voting), your votes will never be automatically reversed by that process, and it does take a human to audit votes that were cast over time.

Answer (score 1):

> Would consistently answering these questions be considered vote fraud or sock-puppetry?

It might be *considered* so. Even if you deal exclusively with this user, it's still not vote fraud as long as he and you follow voting and ask/answer guidelines like everyone else, give no special treatment and have no ulterior motive to benefit one or both, nobody can complain about your voting and answering patterns.